# why it shows "App Requests 1", but no requests listed in the app pages on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image]

just as the picture I attached,  it shows 1 app requests, but there is no apps listed there.

the apprequests sent from the graph api using javascript sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any App Reqeusts you set with you app will need to be deleted by your app.  Sample from blog shows how to concatenate the request_id and user_id in order to delete the outstanding requests.

Refer to http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/569/

---

```
<?php
   require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
   $config = array(
     'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
     'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
   );
   $facebook = new Facebook($config);
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
     <title>Deleting Requests Example</title>
  </head>
 <body>

<?php
   $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
   if ($user_id) {

      //Get the Request Ids
      $request_ids = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']); 

      //Construct full Request_Id
      function build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id) {
          return $request_id . '_' . $user_id;
         }

       //For each Request construct full Request_id and Delete
       foreach ($request_ids as $request_id) { 
     echo ("reqeust_id=".$request_id."<br>");
     $full_request_id = 
           build_full_request_id($request_id,$user_id); 
         echo ("full_reqeust_id=".$full_request_id."<br>");

         try {
           $delete_success =
               $facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
            if ($delete_success) {
                 echo "Successfully deleted " . $full_request_id;
                 }
             else {
                 echo "Delete failed".$full_request_id; 
                }
             }         
          catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                 echo "error";
             }   
          }
    }
    //User TOS if user has not authenticated your App
    else if (!isset($_REQUEST['error'])){        
         $params = array(
          'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/~namitag/requests.php'
         );
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
        echo 
          '<script>window.top.location.href="'.$loginUrl.'";</script>'; 
       }
       else {
         echo ("user denied permission"); }

 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: it doesn't work,I removed the "request_id" + "_" + current_fb_id like this.  FB.ui([request_id] + "_" + [current_fb_id], "delete", function(resp){ alert(response);} . and it alerted "true".  but I still can't find the "app request" in the list on facebook, althrough the count added 1.

Comment: You should be able to use javascript to list that request and get its id,  then you can just send a post to... 

**DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[ < request_id >_< user_id >]?access_token=[ USER or APP ACCESS TOKEN ]**

Comment: the request and user id need to be connect with an underscore  example  123456789_7895412

Comment: thanks  Shawn E Carter  . the app list shows after I configured canvas . but I wanted to redirect to our website when clicked the "accept" button, do you know how to do it?

Comment: stand by for edit.  Is the comment above from this Q&A or another, i do not think i understand your question pertaining to this.

Comment: I got app request listed now, I mean this question fixed, just need to setup the canvas. I asked another question,  when you receive a app request, and you click accept, I wanted to redirect to our app, not the "app on facebook". (as the "app on facebook" shows our app in a iframe.)

Comment: dexterdeng, see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7639264/how-can-i-redirect-to-my-app-page-after-accepted-a-app-request-sent-from-our-app/7639397#7639397  users will land on canvas no matter what but you will redirect them from canvas to your app by adding that url in the data param and and doing a location.href.

Comment: this question fixed after setup the canvas

Comment: hey guys, how did you set up the canvas url?

Comment: @ArnleeVizcayno in the example i used for this, the canvas was set to the root of the domain for both http and https.

Comment: @ShawnECarter: thanks mate, anyway on may case, in iOS, i set it up into facebook app profile and edit its canvas url from empty string to a any url, it works but direct me to an empty view, anyhow soon i know now how it works and soon will change that invalid canvas url to direct to our web app. ^_^